# Book about a panda who ate liquorice and used a sudoku square to do magic

Tags: identification-request

I read a book when I was younger that my grandma brought me and loved it. It was about a panda who ate liquorice and used a sudoku square to do magic. I really would like to find this book for my son

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you remember any more details about this book? E.g. when did you read it (we don't know when you were young), how old was it at that time, was it written in English, which country did you read it in, what was the target age group, was it a picture book or with lots of words, how long was it, ... ? Any little detail could help to narrow down the searches.

Comment: I must have been about 8 or 9 and I remember the book had a white cover with the panda on. I seem to think his name may have been izzy but not sure. It wasnt a picture book and I think the author was male as I seem to recall my grandma had it signed by him. Hope this helps

Comment: Ohhh it woukd have been late 80s early 90s

Answer (score 7):

[Issi Noho.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Issi_Noho)

> Issi Noho is a panda with magic powers. His magic results from completing the vacant square in a series of magic number squares that he inherited from his Chinese ancestors. In a magic square the numbers must come to the same total in whichever direction they are added up, horizontally, vertically or diagonally. Issi's poor arithmetic causes frequent mathematical errors, with unexpected and humorous consequences.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @user10665 Are you the same person who posted this question? It seems like you've lost access to your original account, but you can [merge your accounts](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). Then you'll be able to comment freely on this thread (instead of posting as "answers"), and also mark this answer as accepted if it's correct.